# Python FTP util that enables ssh-dss public key algorithm

Tags: python, ftp, sftp, ftplib, pysftp

I work on a python script with FTP connection. I am unable to connect to the FTP with ftplib.FTP and pysftp.

Manual FTP connection works, but I must enable the dss-ssh algorithm which is disabled by default in the current openSSH version.
Which configuration is missing from my script?

Manual connection:

```
$ sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss ftp_address
```

My script using pysftp:

```
import pysftp
srv = pysftp.Connection(host=my_host, password=my_pass)
```

stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2411, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1802, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "/ftp_tool.py", line 8, in <module>
    srv = pysftp.Connection(host=my_host, password=my_pass)
  File "/ftp_service/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
  File "/ftp_service/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host my_host found.
```

Using Python 3.4.3

Comment: Perhaps you could try [`paramiko`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#module-paramiko.sftp)

Comment: Indeed, as instructed by mhawke and Martin, I used paramiko.
Another issue I had is that the hostname was not resolved by paramiko. 
For now I use the IP address directly. 

I will investigate further, should the time allow it.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP and FTP are two completely unrelated protocols.

You cannot connect with FTP protocol (ftplib) to SFTP server.

pysftp/Paramiko should work. If it does not, post a new question specifically about pysftp/Paramiko, with more details.

Comment: Thank you Martin. pysftp does not work as well - I edited my question to contain the pysftp code + exception.

Comment: You have two questions. One about choosing library for SFTP (I've answered that). And one about pysftp not working. That's a different question. Consider asking a separate one. And make sure you specify a version of Paramiko and pysftp that you are using.